# Find and disable jQuery function that triggers the tab module

Tags: jquery, html, tabs

The website is http://www.cscc.org.sg

The home page has a section, Services This Weekend, which I build using the Divi Builder - Tab Module.

I like to set the last tab title to link to another page.  I can use jQuery to insert the link.  My problem is that even though i can insert the link and I can see the link in the code (see attached screenshot which I set it up on my test instance).

[image: Not only the live site but on my testing instance.]

Here's my jQuery code:

```
   <script>
        var $=jQuery.noConflict(); 
        $("ul > li").last().find("a").attr("href", "http://www.google.com"); 
   </script>
```

What I suspect is that the Tab Module has its own jQuery which triggers Tab content to display when you click on the link.

Can someone help me find this jQuery function?

I also need help on how to disable this jQuery when someone click on the last tab.

I tried this on HTML (https://jsfiddle.net/ckctam34/L4fvyr70/) and it works well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I realized I can use JS to help me.

The code works by when you click on that link, it will trigger a Javascript function to redirect to the new page.

So I use jQuery to add the link with its own ID at the end of the list.

```
<script> var $=jQuery.noConflict(); 
$("ul.et_pb_tabs_controls").append("<li style='line-height: 2em;' id='other'><a onclick='abc();' href='http://www.cscc.org.sg/home/planning-a-visit/#weekly-services'>Other Services</a></li>"); 
</script>
```

I add the following Javascript function:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function abc() {
  window.location='http://www.cscc.org.sg/home/planning-a-visit#weekly-services';
}
</script>
```